# Multiple edit windows for a unit in Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, edit

I need multiple edit windows for a unit in Delphi XE7, so I right click in the edit window and select New Edit Window. But instead of opening a second instance of the unit, the unit is removed from the original edit window, and it is displayed in a new edit window.

I have tried using Classic Undocked layout, Default Layout, Debug Layout, <None>, but the result is always the same.

I have used the feature in the past successfully, this is the first time I encounter this behavior.

Anyone has a clue why this might be happening ?

Comment: I think it must be something about your set-up.  If I have a unit open in XE7 and go to View | New edit window, I get the second instance of the unit you are expecting.  Same for Seattle Update #1.  Fwiw, I have Embedded Designer set to False under Form Design in the registry for both versions.

Comment: Please describe exact steps to reproduce

Comment: Well, the exact steps are that I right click inside the edit window of the unit I want to have a second instance of, and select New Edit Window. This is exactly the same as going to the View menu and selecting New Edit Window. I have also Embedded Designer set to False, just like you have. I have tried all the possible Layouts because I have read in another thread that this might be causing side effects, but nothing has changed. Thanks anyway !!!

Comment: " I have also Embedded Designer ..."  Oh.  In that case, I suppose it might be some 3rd party iDE add-in or component library.  My Seattle is a relatively fresh install doesn't have any of either of these.

Comment: I am not using 3rd party IDE add-ins. I have installed Jedi components and libraries, but I'm not aware of any IDE add-ins.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be caused by the `Embedded Designer` setting in recent versions of Delphi.  By default, in the registry, under `Form Design` this is set to `True` and results in the behaviour that the code editor and form designer cannot be viewed at the same time.

You can revert to the previous behaviour, where you *can* see the designer and the code editor at the same time by changing `Embedded Designer` to `False`.

I just checked XE7 and Seattle update #1 and with `Embedded Designer` set to `True`, I get the behaviour you describe (unit moved to second window), whereas with it set to `False` I get the 'traditional' behaviour you were expecting/hoping for.

In case it makes a difference, I use the "Classic Undocked" desktop layout in the IDE both for design & coding and debugging, but I tested XE7 with the "None" setting and still got the different behaviours I've described.

**Update**

I'm fairly sure that if we could do a side-by-side comparison of your XE7 registry settings and mine, there would be a difference which accounts for the different behaviour you get; the problem is that the .Reg export file for mine is a bit over 30Mb and I only have the supplied 3rd party components installed.

What you could do, after backing up your registry and BDS appdata folder as mentioned in the article below, is to clear out your XE7 registry settings using the `cleanregistryide` switch, reinstate  `Embedded Designer` = `False` and then see if you still get the problem.  Heed the warning that says that `cleanregistryide` should be used only as a last resort!

```
ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe7/rad/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options.html
```

Comment: Embedded designer = False. I never use the embedded designer since I don't like it. I have also used every available Layout.

Comment: Yes, I saw your other comment.  Atm, with Embedded Designer set to false, I simply cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe, the IDE always opens a second instance of the unit in the new Edit Window.  However, while experimenting, i have noticed that certain sequences of switching between code windows and the form designer provoke exceptions in one of the IDE BPLs, but nothing reproducible yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a new EDIT window in Delphi then you need to have at least two units opened at the same time (two unit tabs).

Then you either use `View -> New Window` or right click anywhere in your code and then selecting `New Window` from the Popup menu that is opened.

This will open your current active unit in a new window.

I'm not sure for Delphi XE7 but in Delphi 10 Seattle you can even use docked Layout and it still works.

EDIT: 
This won't work if you have only one unit opened in which case clicking on `View -> New Window` or `New Window` inside a popup menu won't do anything.

I think this could be considered as a bug and thus reported to Embarcadero. That is if it hasn't already been reported.

Comment: (updated) I've tested XE4, XE6, XE7, XE8 and Seattle, in each case with Embedded Designer = False.  In each case, the IDE **will** open another instance of the same unit in a new Edit Window, even if it is the **only** unit open in the IDE.  It sounds from what you say as if your system behaves differently.

Comment: @MartynA Do you perhaps keep `Welcome page` tab open? I'm always closing it. And yes having `Welcome page` tab open besides one unit tab it does work. So I guess it only needs at least two tabs to be open.

Comment: Interesting query: Usually I have the `Welcome page` closed, but trying to get to the bottom of the differences between the behaviour I get and yours and the OP's, I've tried leaving the WP, and all the other optional IDE windows open, but I get the same behaviour every time, even with a **single** tab open.  There must be some factor which accounts for the differences we see, but I'm running out of ideas as to what it might be.  I'm using Win10 64-bit, btw.

Comment: @MartynA Perhaps you didn't understand me correctly. it also works for me if I have a WP open besides a unit (two tabs) but not if I only have a unit open (one tab). Actually I figured that out after quickly trying to test this behavior after your comment to my answer in which case I didn't bother to close the WP tab.

Comment: Actually, I think I did follow your comment.  Try this: Close the WP and every other window in the IDE, icluding the code editor and form designer.  Then, go to File | Open and open any .Pas file.  Then immediately go to View | New edit menu.  If I do that, I now have two Edit Windows open on the .Pas file.  I get the same if I also open a .Dpr ile before the .Pas one.

Comment: @MartynA If I do what you say it does not open me a new edit window. Simply nothing happens.

Comment: Strange difference isn't it?  Do you have any 3rd party add-ins or components installed (apart from the ones that come with Delphi)?  The OP mentioned Jedi.   My XE7 and Seattle are default installs of the Enterprise versions with no extras/add-ins.

Comment: @MartynA Correction. Nothing happens if I have only one tab open and that unit belongs to a form (has design window). But if that unit is a standalone unit (no form attached to it and therefore no design window) it works. So there is definitely some bug in Delphi for this strange behavior.

Comment: @MartynA If I have two or more units that belong to their forms open then it works OK. So yeah something realy strange is happening in Delphi. And no I don't have any add-ins installed. A clean Delphi 10 Seattle professional.

Comment: I have 4 units open, including the welcome page. I can't figure out this behavior. I think I will report it as a bug to Embarcadero.

Comment: That might be the best course of action because something related to this feature really doesn't work as it should.